# Shopify speed test on Googlepage Insight Giving Error

Tags: shopify, google-pagespeed

Below is the link to my Shopify website it is first running good with the test but unfortunately, it start giving me errors while doing a speed test on Google Page Insights.
Error is regarding
"Lighthouse returned error: NOT_HTML. The page provided is not HTML (served as MIME type text/plain)."
I've removed everything unnecessary from the coding but still getting the error. Also Find this error on google but it is not helping me. Any Suggestions would be appreciated

https://thebrooklyn.co.nz/products/orthopedic-calming-pet-bed-for-dogs-cats

Comment: What is in your logs? Plain text is an error message. You have [several errors](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fthebrooklyn.co.nz%2Fproducts%2Forthopedic-calming-pet-bed-for-dogs-cats).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with Lighthouse. Confirmed on Twitter with SEO at Shopify and Chrome dev noted in Github issues that they're aware and working on it: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13379